# How to set the size of of characters in the input window of TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

Look at this picture. I think the characters are too small.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your post because the screen is from TeXworks, the editor supplied with your MiKTeX distribution.

To set greater characters, go to `Format > Font` and choose the size you prefer in the window `Select font` that appears.

I have the Italian version:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very useful for me. But I go to Format->Font to change the size of characters because I don't see the option 'character'.

Comment: @Y.Li I have the Italian version, hence maybe my translations are wrong, I'll correct `Character` with `Font`, thank you for having warned me!